# Django filter with regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I want to write regex for django's model's  charField. That regex contains all letters and last character contains "/".

Eg: "sequences/"

I return regex as follows,

```
Model.objects.filter(location_path__iregex=r'^[a-zA-Z]/$')
```

It is not showing filter data.
demo data for location_path is ['sequences/', 'abc/xyz/', 'abc/aaaa/aaa', 'pqr/']

I want to filter data like 'sequences/', 'pqr/' which contains any character from a-z and field end with '/'

Please give me the proper regex pattern and syntax

Answer (score 22):

You need to add `+` after the character class, so that it would match one or more letters,

```
r'^[a-zA-Z]+/$'
```

Comment: Also, looking at examples, it is needed to add `/`: `r^[a-zA-Z/]+/$`

Comment: no, `I want to filter data like 'sequences/', 'pqr/' `. He wants to filter out only theses two datas from the above list.