# Django - filtering by a portion of the key within a list

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some data in a django 1.8 table:
"key" column values = "a.2", "b.4", "c.6"
I want to filter it by ["a", "b"] and ignore the parts after the dot.

```
Blog.objects.filter(key__startswith=['a','b'])
```

returns nothing

```
Blog.objects.filter(key__contains=['a','b'])
```

returns nothing

```
Blog.objects.filter(key__in=['a%','b%'])
```

returns nothing

Is there an efficient way to do this as opposed to looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try it with `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Blog.objects.filter(Q(key__startswith='a') | Q(key__startswith='b'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

Or using `regex` or `iregex`:

```
Blog.objects.filter(key__iregex=r'^(a|b)\.')
```

Comment: but you're assuming that the list has two values. That would not solve my problem. Thanks though

Comment: Maybe a regex? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803822/django-filter-with-regex

Comment: Official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#iregex

Comment: I like the regex solution although I'm not sure what the consequences of the key list growing will be. I'll mark this as resolved if there is no other solution in a day. Thanks.