# Regex pattern matching in a JsonField which is a list Django

Tags: python, django, django-filters

My jsonfield looks like this:

```
data:
[
  {
     key1: "some value", 
     key2: 20202
  },
  {
     key1: "some value", 
     key2: 20202
  },
  {
     key1: "some value", 
     key2: 20202
  } 
]
```

Now I want to do regex pattern matching on key1(s) of the data field.

How can I do this with Django filter?
for regex this question covers things:
[Django filter with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803822/django-filter-with-regex)

any suggestion, StackOverflow reference will help, thanks

Comment: Why don't you turn it into a Python object and manipulate the list of dicts rather than the text representation as JSON?

Comment: Except for a PostgreSQL database, you can not filter on the content of the JSON fields. But even then, it is quite "complicated" to do so. If the structure is always the same, it might be better to make a model where you store the `key1` and `key2`s as columns.

Comment: Thierry if I understood you correctly, data here is a column. 
I am trying to query a list of objects which match the pattern

Comment: Willem, I am using PostgreSQL, I can't really change the model here.

I want to iterate over each list item, something like how __contains works.